# EF migrations add failed

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, blazor

please advise. I have a **Blazor WASM** project, Visual Studio 2022. After a long time, I am performing an **add migration to ef, but it fails** during execution. The program can be compiled and run. I have already tried deleting the bin and obj directories, recompiling the project and updating the libraries.
If someone could point me to where the error is, I would be glad. Thank you.

```
dotnetef migrations add change15 --context AppDbContext --verbose

Using project 'C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\Vks.Server.csproj'.
Using startup project 'C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\Vks.Server.csproj'.
Writing 'C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\obj\Vks.Server.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\datel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpAB4D.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\Vks.Server.csproj
Writing 'C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\obj\Vks.Server.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\datel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpACB6.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\Vks.Server.csproj
Build started...
dotnet build C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\Vks.Server.csproj /verbosity:quiet /nologo

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.66
Build succeeded.
dotnet exec --depsfile C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\bin\Debug\net7.0\Vks.Server.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\datel\.nuget\packages --runtimeconfig C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\bin\Debug\net7.0\Vks.Server.runtimeconfig.json C:\Users\datel\.nuget\packages\dotnet-ef\7.0.7\tools\net6.0\any\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll migrations add change15 --context AppDbContext --assembly C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\bin\Debug\net7.0\Vks.Server.dll --project C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\Vks.Server.csproj --startup-assembly C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\bin\Debug\net7.0\Vks.Server.dll --startup-project C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\Vks.Server.csproj --project-dir C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\ --root-namespace Vks.Server --language C# --framework net7.0 --working-dir C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server --verbose
Using assembly 'Vks.Server'.
Using startup assembly 'Vks.Server'.
Using application base 'C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\bin\Debug\net7.0'.
Using working directory 'C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server'.
Using root namespace 'Vks.Server'.
Using project directory 'C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\'.
Remaining arguments: .
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly 'Vks.Server'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'dotnet, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Systém nemůže nalézt uvedený soubor.
File name: 'dotnet, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyName, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext, RuntimeAssembly requestingAssembly, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingHostBuilderExtensions.ApplyDefaultAppConfiguration(HostBuilderContext hostingContext, IConfigurationBuilder appConfigBuilder, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder..ctor(HostApplicationBuilderSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder..ctor(WebApplicationOptions options, Action`1 configureDefaults)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.CreateBuilder(WebApplicationOptions options)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\datel\Source\vks\Server\Program.cs:line 23
   at Program.<Main>(String[] args)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.HostingListener.CreateHost()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<ResolveHostFactory>b__0(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<ResolveServiceProviderFactory>b__3(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.AppServiceProviderFactory.CreateFromHosting(String[] args)
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Could not load file or assembly 'dotnet, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Systém nemůže nalézt uvedený soubor.
No application service provider was found.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'AisDbContext'.
Found DbContext 'AppDbContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Vks.Server.Data.AppDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Vks.Server.Data.AppDbContext'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

**Edit 1:**

Added link to *.csproj, Program.cs and AppDbContext.cs files.

https://github.com/Clyde256/share/tree/main

Comment: Can you share csproj and setup/register of the AppDbContext?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I edited the post to add a link to a few files from the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now I've found what's causing my problem.
I recently modified the application to be able to use it as a windows service. And here is probably the problem. I'm probably using WebApplication.CreateBuilder(...) wrong. Currently my Program.cs starts as follows:

```
string workDir = Path.GetFullPath(".");
var appRootDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

var opts = new WebApplicationOptions() { ContentRootPath = appRootDir, Args = args, ApplicationName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName };
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(opts);

builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
```

Which causes a problem when creating the migration. However, as soon as I use the following code to create WebApplication.CreateBuilder(), the migration is successfully created.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

What exactly I'm doing wrong I don't know yet, but I'll find out ;)

Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to
> create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns
> supported at design time, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Did you check that link out?

To run migrations from console you need Design Time elements:

1. Add Package Reference "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design".
2. Include a Design Time DbContext Factory such as below:

**Design Time Factory**

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>
{
    public AppDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Your Dev Env ConnectionString");

        return new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```